# websocket communication between servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I read a lot on Stackoverflow, but after a week of thinking and research, I am running stuck...

So I really have to ask :)

Hope I explain the problem correctly, if not, please say!

The problem is simple. I need 2 servers...
Server A - inserts into database every 15 minutes
Server B - does stuff with the data from server A.

Its easy to let server B do a http request to Server A for data, but what I really want, is that server B gets a 'socket update' from server A, whenever it updates the database data.

Problem: Server B is not always on the same URL.... So the database server cannot simply do a get/post request, because it will not always know Server B's URL.

Possible solution:
Server B can start a socket.io connection to the database server. Keeping the line open to server A, so that server A can respond with its new database data, over the already established socket connection.

So is it possible to have a common socket.io connection between 2 servers, same way as a socket.io connection between a server and a client?

Comment: just use socket.io-client dependency on the client server

Comment: Hmm looks like the way to go! I'm gonna try it, gonna give an upvote for solution if it works :)

Comment: @zaynetro, Do you know if both sides have to use the socket.io-client? Cause I keep gettings 404 error when I try to connect to that server....

Comment: one of the sides must be a server

Comment: Yessss!! I fixed it.. Don't know exactly how :p But I have a bit of a weird configuration going on right now behind ngrok, and still behind the same routers... Thanks you very much! I'm gonna have to figur out how I can put you're answer as the solution...

Comment: Just left the answer

Comment: Have you consider using a Messaging Server since the data is pool on a 15min time frame?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of timeframes and also non regular ticks, so I decided to do a Redis pub/sub approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For server to server communication you can use [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) dependency on one of them and [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) on the other.

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible, servers are often clients of other servers.  You can also make a server listen on more than one port -- server A could listen for connections from server B (B with the changing url) could establish the connection to poll for changes from A.  Or, like you said, to have A push them.

You can use the `http` node module to make requests; here's a summary:

```
http = require('http');
var call = http.request(
    { hostname: "google.com",
      port: 80,
      path: "/",
      method: "GET",
      auth: "user" + ":" + "password"
    },
    function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(err) {
            console.log("Response was", data);
        });
    }
);
req.write("");
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment! :) But yes I also think its possible.. But the problem im running into inside my head... Is that a browser 'starts' a client connection... How can I let a server 'start' a socket connection to another server..

Comment: the `http` module can make requets; there are also npm packages like `restify` that can be useful if more sophisticated functionality is needed.  I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: yes but thats my point on the question.. Its not hard to do a http request.. But the database server cannot do a http back, cause it will not always now the correct url of the servers that are 'listening'.. Thats why socket.io looks like a perfect solution.. a http request will close after a while, and to what url should the database post its data to then??

Comment: ah.  Does B know when its url changes?  It could send a message to A to tell it the latest url.  Or B could check every minute to see if A has anything new for it (instead of keeping the connection open)

Comment: Yes I could send a request, telling about my new url... But its a bit tricky.. Maybe its the way to go.. But I'm still hoping I can do it in a socket.io kind of way.. So that a connection simply 'opens' en 'closes' :)