# Is it possible to have server to server communication with websockets?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to have 2 servers communicate with each other, I'm pretty new to websockets so its kind of confusing. Also, just to put it out there, i'm not trying to do this: [websocket communication between servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605460/websocket-communication-between-servers);

My goal here is to basically use a socket to read data from another server (if this is possible?) I'll try to easily explain more below;

We'll assume there is a website called https://www.test.com (going to this website returns an object)

With a normal HTTP request, you would just do:

```
$.get('https://www.test.com').success(function (r) {
    console.log(r)
})
```

And this would return r, which is an object thats something like this {test:'1'};

Now from what I understand with websockets, is that you cannot return data from them because you don't actually 'request' data, you just send data through said socket.

Since I know what test.com returns, and I know all of the headers that i'm going to need, is it possible to just open a socket with test.com and wait for that data to be changed without requesting it?

I understand how client-server communication works with socketio/websockets im just not sure if its possible to do server-server communication.

If anyone has any links to documentation or anything trying to help explain, it would be much appreciated, I just want to learn how this works. (or if its even possible)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I you can do what (assuming I understood your needs correctly).  You can establish a websocket connection between two servers and then either side can just send data to the other.  That will trigger an event at the other server and it will receive the sent data as part of that event.  You can do this operation either direction from serverA to serverB or vice versa or both.

In node.js, everything is event driven.  So, you would establish the webSocket connection and then just set up an event handler to be triggered when data arrives.  The other server can then just send new data whenever it has updated data to send.  This is referred to as the "push" model.  So, rather than serverA asking serverB is it has any new data, you establish the webSocket connection and serverB just sends new data to serverA whenever that new data is available.  Done correctly, this is both more efficient and more timely (as there is no polling interval and no cycles wasted asking for data when there is nothing new).

The identical model can be used between servers or client to server.  The only difference with the client/server model is that the webSocket must be initially established client to server.  With the server to server model, either server can initiate the connection.

You can think of a webSocket connection like establishing a phone call.  Once the phone call is established, either side can just say something and the other end hears what they're saying.  The webSocket connection is similar.  Once its established, either side can just send some data to the other end and the other end will receive it.  It's an open pipeline ready to have data sent either way.  In node.js, when data arrives on that pipeline, it triggers and event so the listener will get that event and see the data that was sent.

Comment: Wow, the analogy with the phones actually made me understand sockets, it makes much sense on how they work in general now, thank you!

Comment: So, I think i should've mentioned this in my original post, I was following along with what you had said above. We'll say I'm server A, I have no access to server B (server B is https://www.test.com that returns {'test':1}) As server A, I want to listen for when that object gets changed, and then send data to server B. This is possible by just establishing a connection with server B? The thing that confuses me, is how can i know when that object on test.com gets changed? because websockets dont actually request anything.

Comment: @netsocket - Whoever owns the object has to SEND changes to the other server over the webSocket.  There's no way for a remote serverB to "watch" an object inside of serverA without serverA cooperating and sending it a message whenever the object changes.